# Validate lowercase input by user

Tags: php

Using this code which works fine if the user enters all capital letters. However, I need to automatically accept lowercase and sentence case as valid inputs by the user. Currently, this doesnt work, any ideas?

```
add_filter( 'gform_field_validation_17_4', 'custom_validation', 10, 4 );
function custom_validation( $result, $value, $form, $field ) {
    $arrWhitelist = array('KNITS10', 'KATNA20');
    if ( $result['is_valid'] && !in_array( $value, $arrWhitelist )) {
        $result['is_valid'] = false;
        $result['message'] = 'Incorrect code';
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [strtoupper()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php), to make the users input match yours:

```
add_filter( 'gform_field_validation_17_4', 'custom_validation', 10, 4 );
function custom_validation( $result, $value, $form, $field ) {
    $arrWhitelist = array('KNITS10', 'KATNA20');
    if ( $result['is_valid'] && !in_array( strtoupper($value), $arrWhitelist )) {
        $result['is_valid'] = false;
        $result['message'] = 'Incorrect code';
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Or intercept input on browser end and change it with javascript so it is entered all upper case to begin with

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [strcasecmp()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php), but the cleaner option in this scenario would be strtoupper.

The resulting code using strcasecmp would be:

```
    function custom_validation($result, $value, $form, $field)
    {
        $arrWhitelist = array('KNITS10', 'KATNA20');
        array_walk(
            $arrWhitelist, function ($item) use ($value, $result) {
            if (strcasecmp($item, $value) === 0) {
                $result['is_valid'] = false;
                $result['message'] = 'Incorrect code';
            }
        }
        );
        return $result;
    }
```